# Receive message SmartEyeglass ControlExtension

Tags: android, messaging, sony, sony-smartwatch

I want to make an app for Sony SmartEyeglass where the App on the Phone and the ControlExtension exchange data on runtime.

It's pretty obvious how to send messages from the app to the extension...

```
public void startExtension(String msg) {
    if (HelloWorldExtensionService.Object != null) {
        HelloWorldExtensionService.Object
                .sendMessageToExtension(msg);
    }
}
```

but how do I get the `msg` in my ControlExtension, if the extension is already running?
I didn't find an `onMessageReceived(String message)` method for the class ControlExtension.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Intents the same way you would for an standard Android app.  For example from your Activity:

```
Intent intentBuzz = new Intent();
intentBuzz.setAction(buzzIntent);
mContext.sendBroadcast(intentBuzz);
```

Then in your Control Extension register a broadcast receiver:

```
buzzReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    buzzAction();
}
};
registerReceiver(buzzReceiver, new IntentFilter(buzzIntent));
```

This works the other way around as well if you want to pass something other than a string.